# Existe algo parecido com o método ".format" de Python em Java?

Tags: java

Eu estive estudando a linguagem Java e me dei conta de que estou usando muitos sinais de concatenação (+).

E me lembrei que na linguagem Python, há o método `format`, em que pode-se usar as chaves para diminuir o uso de concatenações.

Gostaria de saber se, em Java é possível fazer a mesma coisa?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/512957/112052

Answer (score 2):

Em Java concatenações de strings com `+` são bastante comuns. Na maior parte dos casos o compilador é esperto o suficiente para traduzir concatenações com `+` para concatenações usando `StringBuilder` e `append`; dessa maneira  `+` costuma ser o idioma mais natural para concatenar strings em Java. Nos casos em que *performance* é importante e a lógica é complexa demais para ser otimizada pelo compilador podemos usar `StringBuilder` diretamente.

Para formatação "avançada" existe o método [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) que usa strings de formatação bem parecidas com as usadas na função `printf` do C.

```
String mensagem = String.format("%d %s custam $%0.2f", 6, "bananas", 1.74);
```

Para formatação "básica" existe também a classe [`MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/text/MessageFormat.html) que usa *patterns* parecidos com os *placeholders* posicionais do `format` do Python.

```
String mensagem = MessageFormat.format("{0} {1} custam {2,number,currency}", 6, "bananas", 1.74);
```

Finalmente, também é possível usar uma solução externa como [Better Strings](https://github.com/antkorwin/better-strings) que permite interpolação de strings em projetos Java.