# Há como interpolar strings em Java?

Tags: java, string, concatenação-de-string

Estou começando no Java e achei o caminho para concatenar String e variáveis muito cansativo.

Em JavaScript, podemos utilizar `` `string ${variavel}` ``; em Python,
`'string {}'.format(variavel)` ou `f'string {variavel}'` etc.

Gostaria de saber se existe algo assim no Java ou alguma forma de simplificar a concatenação que não seja assim:

```
"string" + variavel + "string"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em Java, uma opção é usar [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax):

```
String nome = "Fulano";
int idade = 20;

System.out.printf("%s tem %d anos\n", nome, idade); // Fulano tem 20 anos
```

A sintaxe da string de formatação é inspirada no C, por isso você deve indicar o tipo de cada informação sendo exibida (no caso acima, `%s` indica uma string e `%d` indica um número inteiro). [Veja a documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) para mais detalhes.

**Vale lembrar que `printf` é mais do que simplesmente concatenar**, já que você pode escolher opções de alinhamento e preenchimento (por exemplo, imprimir o texto alinhado à direita, ocupando 20 posições, ou imprimir o número com zeros à esquerda, inclusive determinando a quantidade, etc). Por exemplo, `%05d` faria o número acima ser impresso como `00020`.

Enfim, para ver todas as opções, consulte a já citada documentação. É um mecanismo mais poderoso do que a simples concatenação, então você deve escolher o que for mais adequado para o seu caso (não use como critério "*é mais curto*" ou "*cansa menos*", use o que faz mais sentido para o que você precisa fazer).

---

Mas se em vez de imprimir, você quiser gerar uma string com o resultado da concatenação/formatação, aí pode usar [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)), cuja sintaxe é similar:

```
String mensagem = String.format("%s tem %d anos", nome, idade);
```

Ou se estiver usando uma versão do Java superior a 15:

```
String mensagem = "%s tem %d anos".formatted(nome, idade);
```

---

Outra opção é usar `java.text.MessageFormat`, cuja sintaxe lembra um pouco mais o `format` do Python:

```
String mensagem = MessageFormat.format("{0} tem {1} anos", nome, idade);
```

Mas esta classe possui algumas opções interessantes, como por exemplo configurar o texto para singular e plural:

```
String mensagem = MessageFormat.format("{0} tem {1} {1,choice,1#ano|1<anos}", nome, idade);
```

Assim, se a idade for `1`, a mensagem será `Fulano tem 1 ano`, mas se for diferente de `1` (por exemplo, `20`), aí será `Fulano tem 20 anos`. Novamente, não deixe de ver na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/text/MessageFormat.html) todas as opções disponíveis.

---

## Atualização: Java 21

Ontem (19/09/2023) foi lançado o [JDK 21](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk/21/), e agora temos mais uma opção: [*String Templates*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430).

> **Atenção**: esta funcionalidade ainda está como "[*preview*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/12)", ou seja, vem desabilitada por padrão e não há garantia de que permaneça igual em futuras versões. Ainda pode sofrer alterações, então por enquanto, use por conta e risco.

Para usá-la, deve-se habilitar explicitamente:

- Compilando com `javac --release 21 --enable-preview Arquivo.java` e depois rodando com `java --enable-preview Arquivo`
- Ou usando o [*source code launcher,*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/330), rodando diretamente com `java --source 21 --enable-preview Arquivo.java`

No caso, ficaria assim:

```java
String nome = "Fulano";
int idade = 20;

System.out.println(STR."\{nome} tem \{idade} anos"); // Fulano tem 20 anos
```

O [pré-processador `STR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringTemplate.html#STR) é importado automaticamente por *default*, e basta interpolar as variáveis dentro do *template*.

Outra opção é o [pré-processador `FMT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/FormatProcessor.html#FMT), que permite que se use as opções de formatação (as mesmas de `printf`). Mas ao contrário de `STR`, não é importado automaticamente:

```java
import static java.util.FormatProcessor.FMT;

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nome = "Fulano";
        int idade = 20;
        System.out.println(FMT."%-10s\{nome}|%4d\{idade}");
    }
}
```

No caso, a opção `%-10s` diz para alinhar a string à esquerda, usando 10 espaços, e `%4d` diz para alinhar o número à direita, ocupando 4 espaços. O resultado é:

```
Fulano    |  20
```

Answer (score 6):

Em Java você tem a classe [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) para isso. E de fato ela é mais adequada em várias situações. Existem outras opções, a própria classe [`string`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) possui uma.

Só não diria que ela é menos cansativa. De qualquer forma se isso é cansativo eu sugeriria pensar em trabalhar com outra coisa, você tem que fazer o que é mais adequado, não importa o trabalho que dá. E eu acho que formatar é mais trabalhoso que concatenar (não que isso mude muita coisa). Mas concatenar costuma ser menos vantajoso que formatar, ainda que no contexto específico talvez não seja (a implementação pode ter otimização em alguns cenários e o compilador fazer ficar igual a concatenação). Formatar tende ser mais trabalhoso.

Programar é entender o que está fazendo e escolher o melhor mecanismo para o contexto, não o que é mais fácil de digitar, ou que parece mais bonitinho.

Dependendo de onde for usar tem uma variedade de métodos que usam a `Formatter` para você, [exemplo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) é se for imprimir já que alguns métodos de impressão já possuem o formatação interna. Aqui o trabalho de formatar fica reduzido, mas só pode usar em cenário de de console ou outro que tenha um mecanismo de formatação interno onde o texto será usado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).